# Typescript compiler bug renaming javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a reference to this module found here:

https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections

And I reference it in my typescript projects like this:

```
///<reference path='..\..\libs\collections.ts'/>
```

I use grunt to compile the project:

```
    typescript: {
        server: {
            src: ['src/server/**/*.ts'],
            dest: ['bin/server'],
            options: {
                module: 'commonjs',
                base_path: 'src/server',
                target: 'es5'
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway, for some reason the compiler is outputting the file as either **ctions.js** or **lections.js**, as though its truncating the name somehow.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Ok so after some experimentation, I renamed the module to "testing" and the name gets truncated to ng.js. It seems that something within this module is modifying the output file name.

Comment: If you change the reference tag to an absolute path, do you still see the problem? It could be a grunt problem where they're manipulating the path incorrectly -- it's probably not a coincidence it's taking off 3 or 5 characters (length of .. and ..\.. respectively)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a grunt problem. Try compiling with `tsc` manually or check out grunt-ts : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts